# AS3 How to import a button

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am new to flash AS3.  I inserted a button and gave it the name login_btn.

Now in my action script, i want to do a login_btn.visible = false;  However I'm not sure what "class" i need to import into my action script file.  Is it `import flash.display.button` or something?

Comment: Try out some tutorials over at http://gotoAndLearn.com I learned almost everything from Lee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to have the

```
login_btn.visible = false;
```

itself. However, for future, you could import it from flash.display packagae.

```
import flash.display.SimpleButton;
```

Hint: If you are not sure what to import, just type

```
var UR_VAR_NAME
```

then put a semi colon ( **:** ), flash will automatically import its class. It is feature of the AS Editor.

Answer (score 1):

If you gave the button an instance name of `login_btn`,  then you just access it from it's parent (whatever timeline you put the button on)

If the parent is a timeline and your not using a document class, then just add a keyframe to the timeline and put this code on it:

```
login_btn.visible = false;
```

---

If you gave it the class name of `login_btn` in the actionscript linkage settings. Then you instantiate it like this:

```
var btn:login_btn = new login_btn();
```

In either case, no imports are necessary as they are automatically taken care of.